# configuring Eclipse for text files

Tags: javascript, eclipse, macos, editor

I'm running Eclipse Indigo on MacOSX. If I open java source files or xml files or .txt files, they show up in Eclipse.

But if I try to open files within Eclipse that are javascript (.js) source files, it brings up DashCode.

How can I fix Eclipse so it will open .js files in its own editor?

---

edit: this is opening an arbitrary .js file outside the Workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the file in the Navigator or Package Explorer view, choose Open With and pick the editor you want to use.

Comment: It's not in the Navigator/Package explorer view -- I want to stop Eclipse from spawning DashCode for .js files and instead open them within Eclipse.

Comment: So this is for .js files that aren't in your workspace?  Do you have a JavaScript Editor installed in Eclipse?  If not, have you tried going to the File Associations preference page and adding an association for that filename extension to an editor that is installed in Eclipse?